# unhashable type: 'numpy.ndarray' error using Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, pie-chart

I'm trying to import data from excel and then create a pie chart with the data. These are the commands used:

```
import pandas as pd 
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
basedatos = pd.read_excel(r'C:\Users\CFK\Documents\Python example\Data Example.xlsx',sheet_name='results')
print(basedatos)

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.plot(basedatos)
plt.show()
```

And I'm getting the following error:

```
TypeError: unhashable type: 'numpy.ndarray'
```

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks in advance

```
 File "C:\Users\CFK\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\category.py", line 116, in default_units axis.set_units(UnitData(data)) 
 File "C:\Users\CFK\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\category.py", line 192, in init self.update(data) 
 File "C:\Users\CFK\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\category.py", line 225, in update for val in OrderedDict.fromkeys(data): TypeError: unhashable type: 'numpy.ndarray' 
 QSocketNotifier: Multiple socket notifiers for same socket 2544 and type Read
```

Comment: Full error message please.

Comment: Here a part of the result @hpaulj



  File "C:\Users\CFK\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\category.py", line 116, in default_units
    axis.set_units(UnitData(data))

  File "C:\Users\CFK\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\category.py", line 192, in __init__
    self.update(data)

  File "C:\Users\CFK\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\category.py", line 225, in update
    for val in OrderedDict.fromkeys(data):

TypeError: unhashable type: 'numpy.ndarray'


QSocketNotifier: Multiple socket notifiers for same socket 2544 and type Read

Comment: If you want a pie chart, why are you using the more generic `plt.plot` command (as opposed to `pie`?).  And why pass the whole dataframe?  I see a `print(basedatos)`, so you must have looked at it - but neglected to show us anything :(.  `matplotlib` is written to work with `numpy` arrays.  It works with `pandas` only to the extent that the frames can be converted to arrays.  You need to read more pandas documentation.